# Parse SDK SaveInBackground never goes in call back

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So i have chatrooms and chatmessages in my app

ChatRoomVC i sent if there's unread messages and update the chatroom that messages has been read.. this is my code

```
 if hasUnreadMessages || getMessagesNow {
        DispatchQueue.background(delay: 0, background: {
            self.thisRoom.readBy!.append(self.currentUser.objectId!)
            self.thisRoom.saveEventually { (saved, err) in
                if err == nil {
                    NSLog("AppDebug -Message Unread updated")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "updateBadgeValue"), object: nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

So its never saving on server and no callback with success or error

i tried saveInBackground.. but that just hangs up the app

if i remove background Dispatch. it hangs up the app as well

any idea why would this be happening? TIA

Edit: Once the saveEventually or SaveInBackground is called, cpu usuage goes up by 60-80% and never goes down. So if i go back and open another room with unread messages.. it goes to 150-160%...so..on

Comment: Can you add some breakpoints and try to figure out which lines are executing after calling `saveEventually`?

Comment: its not coming within the callback

Comment: What do you mean? After saveEventually() no other lines are executed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be calling saveEventually() on a background thread.  The saveEventually() method is already designed to use background threads.

try this...

```
if hasUnreadMessages || getMessagesNow {
            self.thisRoom.readBy!.append(self.currentUser.objectId!)
            self.thisRoom.saveEventually()
    }
```

You can see how this method works in the documentation here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#saving-objects-offline